# QwtPlot updating custom axis

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

Using Qwt I have to make a plot with a custom x-axis, where I can change the scale labels under program execution. 
In order to do so i have overloaded `label` from `QwtScaleDraw` like this:

H-file:

```
class TimeScaleDraw : public QwtScaleDraw
{
public:
    TimeScaleDraw();
    virtual QwtText label(double) const;
    void setTimeScale(double factor, QString unit);
private:
    double factor;
    QString unit;
};
```

Cpp-file:

```
TimeScaleDraw::TimeScaleDraw()
{
    factor = 1.0;
    unit = "s";
}

QwtText TimeScaleDraw::label(double val) const
{
    return QwtText(QString::number(val*factor) + unit);
}

void TimeScaleDraw::setTimeScale(double factor, QString unit)
{
    this->factor = factor;
    this->unit = unit;
}
```

This works fine if i call the method `setTimeScale(2.0, "sec)` from my Qt window constructor. But if i try to call the method when eg. a button is pushed, then it does not do anything?
I have tried by calling `replot()` and `updateAxes()` but this changes nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
I needed to call `invalidateCache()`.